# Passing custom directive attribute to ng-model in template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to pass in some attributes to my `<custom-input>` directive. Like so...

```
<custom-input type="text" name="first_name" title="First Name"></custom-input>
```

However, I'm getting a syntax error for the line where I pass the attribute to `ng-model` in the template.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong? Everything was working before I tried to move into a custom directive.

**Directive**

```
.directive('customInput', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                type: '@type',
                name: '@name',
                title: '@title'
            },
            templateUrl: './assets/templates/custom-input.html',
            controller: function() {
                this.data = {}
                this.focus = null;
            },
            controllerAs: 'input'
        };
    })
```

**Template**

```
<div class="Form__field">
    <input
        ng-model="input.data.{{name}}"
        ng-class="{'Form__input--is-filled': input.data.{{name}}.length > 0}"
        ng-focus="input.focus='{{name}}'"
        ng-blur="input.focus=null"
        class="Form__input"
        type="{{type}}"
        name="{{name}}"
        placeholder="{{title}}"
    />
    <label
        ng-show="input.data.{{name}}.length > 0"
        ng-class="{'Form__label--is-active': input.focus === '{{name}}'}"
        class="Form__label"
        for="{{name}}"
    >{{title}}</label>
    <div
        class="Info Info--default"
        ng-show="input.focus === '{{name}}'">
    </div>
</div>
```

**Error**

> Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' is not a valid
>   identifier at column 12 of the expression [input.data.{{name}}]
>   starting at [{{name}}].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before:

```
input.data.{{name}}
```

After:

```
input.data[name]
```

Comment: That just hardcodes it rather than passing the value of the `name` attribute.

Comment: Not sure what you mean - `scope.name` will evaluate to whatever is passed into the directive.

Comment: The output of the directive is here ```<input ng-model="input.data[name]" ng-class="{'Form__input--is-filled': input.data.email.length &gt; 0}" ng-focus="input.focus='email'" ng-blur="input.focus=null" class="Form__input ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty ng-valid-email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">``` the ng-model should be "input.data.email"

Comment: If `scope.name` evaluates to `"email"`, then `input.data[name]` and `input.data.email` are equivalent. Try it.

Comment: You have to use {{}} with '@', so I think you're more likely to get 'first_name' in there than the contents of a first_name value on the outer scope.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship No, @Dijon is passing the literal `first_name` in, which will be evaluated as a string by the literal binding `@`.

Comment: That's exactly what I just said.

Comment: I think I misunderstood you. Do you mean @Dijon needs to use `{{}}` in the template? If so, that's also not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Your inner scope is getting type, name, and title attached directly to it. By defining the scope in the directive definition, you are declaring an isolate scope--one that no longer has access to the outer scope. You're also not passing in your input object.

What you have is the same as doing this inside the controller:

scope.name = 'first_name';
scope.title = 'First Name';
scope.type = 'text';

If you follow @bchemy's suggestion, you'll get a new property on your empty input.data object called first_name. And then the contents of the input would go into that. But there's no reason to expect that anything will come into it, because you didn't pass anything in that you're putting into that variable.